# "Error while finding spec for 'robot.run' (<class 'ImportError'>: No module named 'UserDict')"

Tags: robotframework

How to solve error "Error while finding spec for 'robot.run' (: No module named 'UserDict')". I get this error when running command pybot from command prompt in Python 3.5

Comment: robot doesn't yet officially run on python 3. Are you using standard robot, or a version of robot from a fork that adds python 3 support?

Comment: robotframework 2.9.2 installed using "pip install robot-framework" on Python 3.5

Comment: Now I run instead pip install robotframework-python3 after reading from the post https://pypi.python.org/pypi/robotframework-python3. Let me check now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Robot framework doesn't yet support python 3.

You might want to try an unofficial fork/port of robot framework. The project is here: https://github.com/userzimmermann/robotframework/tree/python3

According to the documentation at the time I write this, you can install it with pip like this:

```
pip install robotframework-python3
```

Comment: Thanks Bryan.I did it now. Let me check.

Comment: How to verify all is working well. I have Python 3.5 IDE (Windows 7 based)

Comment: Do u recommend using pyCharm.I come from windows background not very comfortable to run commands and instead need a editor to write a test script, run it and test it. I am new baby to Python ( having .net, c,C++,c#) but have a critical task to understand and write *** Test Scripts quickly. What do u suggest to do for that as well!